# SSRS Managing parameters default value different behavior 2007 to 2010

Tags: reporting-services, integrated-mode

Issue:  After uploading a SSRS 2008 R2 RDL to SharePoint 2010, a listing of possible values of a query based parameter is not populated into a dropdown list next to the “use this value” radio button when managing the reports parameters.  The exact same report can be uploaded to SharePoint 2007 and a listing of possible values (that is the result of the specified query) is populated in a checkbox dropdown for the user to select.

Background/Other:
•   The issue occurs with SharePoint 2010 for SQL Server 2008 R2 SSRS Reports running in Integrated Mode with NTLM authentication.

•   It only occurs for query based parameters. Static lists of values populate the dropdown as expected.

•   This occurs for both single valued and multi-valued query based parameters.

•   No JavaScript or other browser-based errors have been witnessed

•   SQL Profiler traces have been captured against the database which the query is to run against and no queries are issued at any point when the parameter management screen is or when the “use this value” radio button is selected.

•   No login failure message are being thrown when the parameter management screen is up or when the “use this value” radio button is selected.

•   This same behavior is reproducible on a secondary development environment

•   This same behavior is reproducible on a virtual machine running SharePoint 2010 with SSRS 2008 R2 in Integrated Mode

•   A similar was logged:  http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/696890/ssrs-manage-parameters-in-sharepoint-2010-dynamic-parameter-values-not-loaded

•   http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/56fd8f3f-9953-4825-86fb-e2f5d729395f

Questions:
•   Is this expected behavior?

•   Is this a known change from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010?

•   If this is not expected behavior is the a known bug that the product team is working?  Any software updated available?

•   Is the only option within SharePoint to override a query-based parameter’s default value is to manually enter data into the textbox for SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was asked in January with no response since (it's now July), I might suggest patching SQL Server 2008 R2 to the latest cumulative update/service pack (as of writing, SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2), and the same for SharePoint Server 2010 (currently June 2012 CU).

Comment: Don't bother worrying about the update - this **is still** an issue after 8 years. It's still in 2012 (and most likely 2016 too).